# Gnome online accounts not syncing with Gnome Shell calendar

Tags: gnome, evolution, empathy, calendar, online-accounts

I'm using Gnome Shell in Ubuntu 11.10. I've recently activated online accounts, which is supposed to sync my Google Calendar with Gnome Shell's calendar. However, it does never sync. I've tried to reboot many times; I've even installed Evolution, but it still doesn't work.

The google docs sync (with Gnome Documents) works fine, but neither the calendar, the mail (it doesn't sync with evolution) or the contacts (empathy) are synced.

So, what could I do to make it work?

Comment: Your issue may be related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-online-accounts/+bug/835498).

Answer (score 1):

As hinted here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=127358

I found that having Evolution running while adding the online account got the email and calendar added as expected.

Comment: Only trouble is, this would require the installation of Evolution, which does not come with 11.10 by default.